# $(P,H)$ Euclidean Hartogs figure

Tags: several-complex-variables

Let $(P,H)$ be a [Euclidean Hartogs figure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hartogs%27_extension_theorem) in $\mathbb{C}^n$ and $f:H\to \mathbb{C}^n$ a holomorphic injective map, then we know that $f$ extend holomorphically to polidisc $P$ (i.e. there is a holomorphic map $F:P\to\mathbb{C}^n$ such that $F\equiv f$ on $H$), is true that $F$ is also injective?

Any hint would be appreciated.